# lastInsertId Possible Issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a small web app in PHP/MySQL as a course project.

When the user creates an account (the account type has to be either Tutor or Student), I follow the following logic to insert him to the database:
Note: There is inheritance between tables that I achieved by making USER as super class, STUDENT and TUTOR both have FKs to user_id

`INSERT INTO USER; // Line A`

```
// The following are Lines B
if (type == 'TUTOR')
     INSERT INTO TUTOR (user_id) VALUES (lastInsertId());
else INSERT INTO STUDENT (user_id) VALUES (lastInsertId());
```

Is it possible that in a large application where there could be 100 clients registering at the same time that this logic fails to do its task correctly?

For example, User-1 (Student) is registering and is now inserted into `USER` first with id=1
And before he is inserted to `STUDENT`, another user User-2 (Tutor) comes and is also registering for the app and he is inserted to `USER` with id=2

Now, execution for User-1 continues and the lastInsertId() is now 2 instead of 1...

Could this happen in a large web app or assuming that there is a large block of code between Line A and Lines B?

Note that I'm NOT using the singleton pattern to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly safe. There is no mix between the values returned by MySQL function [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for different connections. As the documentation states:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for most recent statement affecting an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

I guess the pseudo-code you posted refers to the PHP function [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) which for MySQL wraps the MySQL function [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: yes, you're right about the function. and thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

The last insert id is **specific to the database connection**. It is ***guaranteed*** to return the insert id of the last statement your current connection issued. It is explicitly isolated from other concurrent queries.